# using find with exec and basename to execute a command in the directory of the found file

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I have a tree of directories which contains MSWord files .doc. I want to convert them all to .odt.

The syntax is:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to odt -r --outdir <dir to place the .odt> *.doc
```

I'm trying to use it with `find` to do it all at once. I've tried following:

```
find . -name "*.doc" -exec soffice --headless --outdir dirname {} --convert-to odt {} \;
```

and

```
find . -name "*.doc" -exec soffice --headless --outdir $("dirname '{}'") --convert-to odt {} \;
```

But both of them fail. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-execdir` instead. It will execute the command it the same directory which contains the file. The details are documented in [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/find.1.html).

```
find . -name '*.doc' -exec soffice --headless --convert-to odt {} \;
```

Your first example failed, because `dirname` was interpreted as an argument for exec option. The executed command would have `dirname` as the argument for `--outdir` and have file path after it (as positional argument) `soffice --headless --outdir dirname <file> --convert-to odt <file>`

In second example `$("dirname '{}'")` is evaluated by shell and the output is substituted before executing *find*. The result of the substitution would empty and *"command not found"* would be printed in *stderr*. The executed command would not have the required parameter for `--outdir` at all `soffice --headless --outdir --convert-to odt <file>`